# Etymology of 此 cǐ this, these?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

What is the etymology of cǐ ? How this character means those, these?

Comment: This seems to be two unrelated questions in one, it's usually better to post them as two different questions. It's a bit unclear what you mean by the second one, since, you ask how "c" is pronounced and then give "c" as a possible answer, which means you're talking about different alphabets/transcription systems (which one I don't know, because of "q"). "c" here is the normal Pinyin "c", which is pronounced /t͡sʰ/ (IPA). That's an aspirated affricate, i.e. a stop linked to a fricative (hissing "s" sound), with aspiration (puff of air).

Comment: Wikipedia has a pronunciation sample: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mandarin_Chinese_pronunciation-%E6%AD%A4.wav

Comment: Olle linge the pronunciation part is cleared with your explanation. Thanks. I am deleting the pronunciation part from question

Comment: [tag:etymology] (`Questions about the origin and history of Chinese words`) is a related, but distinct concept from [tag:glyph-origin] (`Questions about the graphical origin and evolution of characters`) - please clarify which one you're asking about (or if you're asking about both).

Comment: dROOOze, my intention is to know how “this” and “these”were evolved for the word 此  . I think it covers both etymology and glyph origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
《說文》：「此，止也。从止从匕。匕，相比次也。凡此之屬皆从此。」

甲金文從「止」從「人」，左右結構與上下結構無別。象人所止步之處，即此處之意，與「彼」相對。

陳初生以為「以腳趾與一側身人形會腳步到此停止之意。」何琳儀以為會以足蹋人之意，「跐」之初文。姑備一說。
```

[此](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%AD%A4) is a compound ideogram comprising 止 and 人 (匕 is a crouching man). One always infers the combined meaning of the two simpler, juxtaposed pictograms.

Multi-function Chinese Character Database adopts the explanation of the scholar Chen Chusheng: With [止](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%AD%A2) being a pictogram for 'foot' at first and later a phonetic loan for 'to stop', the explanation for the meaning of 此 is believed to be that a man (人) arrives 'here' when he stops (phonetic loan 止) his pace (pictogram 止). 'This' and 'these' are derived meanings of 'here', which is understandably figurative.

*Shuowen Jiezi* however argues 'to stop' comes from the character 匕. Being one of the two 'rotated' men in 比, a man stops to compare (meaning of 比) himself with another. This is in accordance to Duan Yucai's annotation 相比次而止也.